# Differentiate WiFi from LAN Network Adapter with Win32_NetworkAdapter class - Visual Basic

Tags: networking, vbscript

I want to deploy a script to avoid PCs to be connected on WiFi and LAN At the same time. I found a VBS script which takes two arguments. A watched adapter and a "backup" one if the watched goes down. So basically if my main adapter goes down, the other one goes up and vice versa. But I have to specify two adapters when I run the script, it's nice but I can't deploy the script on my computer stock. So I tried to improve the script by making a function that would recognize Wireless adapter from LAN and retrieve the name of those two and finally use them instead of my two arguments.

I tried to gather information that would allow me to differentiate those two adapters. I thought I could get that information from AdapterType but both of them are "Ethernet 802.3" instead of "Ethernet 802.3" and "Wireless" like i'd have thought.

Here is my results when I gathered informations about my interfaces (I only pasted the two first, the next ones are irrelevant).

```
AdapterType : Ethernet 802.3
AdapterTypeID : 0
MACAddress : D4:BE:D9:43:D2:4A
NetConnectionStatus : 2
ProductName : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
DeviceID : 7
Availability : 3
PhysicalAdapter : True
ServiceName : e1cexpress
NetConnectionStatus :2
NetConnectionID : toto

AdapterType : Ethernet 802.3
AdapterTypeID : 0
MACAddress : 44:6D:57:5F:6E:C0
NetConnectionStatus : 2
ProductName : Carte Half-Mini de réseau local sans fil Wireless-N DW1501
DeviceID : 11
Availability : 3
PhysicalAdapter : True
ServiceName : BCM43XX
NetConnectionStatus :2
NetConnectionID : tata
```

Also, is a virtual adapter presence can be a problem (VMWare or VirtualBox) during the adapter recognition) ?

Now here's my function. I must say I'm a big n00b in Visual Basic so be gentle :).

```
Function GetNetworkAdapterNames_LAN()
        Dim sConnexionLan', sConnexionWifi
        Dim aConnexionLan, objWMIService
        'Dim sConnexions As New List(Of String)
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

    Set aConnexionLan = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE AdapterType = 'Ethernet 802.3'",,48)
    'Set sConnexionWifi = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE AdapterType = 'Wireless'",,48)
    For Each objItem in aConnexionLan
        WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterType )
        WScript.Echo ( "AdapterTypeID : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        WScript.Echo ( "MACAddress : " & objItem.MACAddress )
        WScript.Echo ( "NetConnectionStatus : " & objItem.NetConnectionStatus )
        WScript.Echo ( "ProductName : " & objItem.ProductName )
        WScript.Echo ( "DeviceID : " & objItem.DeviceID )
        WScript.Echo ( "Availability : " & objItem.Availability )
        WScript.Echo ( "PhysicalAdapter : " & objItem.PhysicalAdapter )
        WScript.Echo ( "ServiceName : " & objItem.ServiceName )
        WScript.Echo ( "NetConnectionStatus :" & objItem.NetConnectionStatus )
        WScript.Echo ( "NetConnectionID : " & objItem.NetConnectionID )
        REM WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        REM WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        REM WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        REM WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        REM WScript.Echo ( "AdapterType : " & objItem.AdapterTypeID )
        WScript.Echo ( " " )


    Next
    'sConnexions.add(sConnexionLan)
    'sConnexions.add(sConnexionWifi)
    'return sConnexionLan 
End Function
```

The main script can be found in the IntelliAdmin script : netswitch.vbs . This is just the function I added to try to retrieve some information to differentiate LAN and WiFi adapters, so it's not really relevant for the moment about the following of the script. 
Anyway, once I'll have found a way to differentiate those two adapters, I'll return their names and replace them where arguments should be.

Thanks for reading and future help, I hope I made my post understandable. :)

EDIT :

I tried to get standard name that should be on every PC of the stock for LAN and WiFi adapter. The script works with that solution but it's very sensitive to adapter name changes.

Here is a pastebin link, i'm afraid it's a bit long to post the whole code here.

http://pastebin.com/4y8EMwVJ

Do you have any ideas to differentiate LAN adapter from WiFi ones ? It could make my script stronger :)